# Include and initially merge sub-projects into git repository

Tags: git

Consider a project structure containing the following three folders

- web (contains a web frontend)
- backend (contains a web backend)
- documentation (contains documentation)

While the documentation is just a regular folder containing some files, the *web* and *backend* folders should refer to the root of some external git repositories. I want to work on my repository and then push the changes of *web* and *backend* to the corresponding repositories.

**Question 1)**

The repository and the related two repositories are only used by me and my team. What would you propose to use, subtrees or submodules? I still don't understand what the differences and consequences are (except for some more complex push commands when using subtrees and many people saying one should avoid submodules at all costs).

**Question 2)**

The folders of my repository do always contain some content. How do I create a submodule/subtree for the folders and initially merge the new submodule/subtree with the contents that are already there?

Comment: I also read a lot that submodules are bad, so I went with subtrees. Honestly, it's not a beautiful experience. But I wrote a couple scripts to simplify things, so I do something like `./pull-shared` and `./push-shared` to take care of the ugly syntax and the sequence of instructions. On question 2, in the worse case, just rename the directory, subtree init, then overwrite the directory. When in doubt, just try on a test repository.

Comment: In my opinion, submodules are not bad, nor are subtrees. Both are valid ways to achieve certain things, and both involve certain amounts of additional complexity that can at times be difficult to get right. I think in the long run, in this particular scenario, submodules are probably the way to go, but you need to spend some time learning what the implications are and figuring out the proper procedures for dealing with them, and understand from the start that there is additional complexity involved.